# How to use list serializer in django to serialize according to inherited serializer?

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-rest-framework, multiple-inheritance, django-serializer

Lets assume there are three models Animal, Cat, Dog where Cat and Dog are inheriting from parent class Animal.

```
class Animal:
   name
class Cat:
   sleep_hours
class Dog:
   breed
```

Considering that sleep_hours and breed are mutually exclusive property of cat and dog respectively. Now we have serializers :-

```
AnimalSerializer:
   name
CatSerializer(AnimalSerializer):
   sleep_hours
DogSerializer(AnimalSerializer):
   breed



Now we want to develop an API where we return all the information about animal so it should return something like this 
[
{'tommy', 'pug'},
{'kitty', '10'},
]
So consider animal class is linked to user i.e. user.animals returns a list of animals (parent class) we want to use modelSerialiser on user.
class UserAnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    animals = AnimalSerializer(read_only=True)

 class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('animals')

Now we want to use different serializer(child serializer) based on the instance type. Is there any good way to handle these type of scenarios. Please comment if there is some confusion about the question.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a *design patterns* solution, but why not have the serializer iterate over (did someone say *iterator* pattern? ;-) ) the fields and serialize them? Why do you need child serializers?
If you don't want the serializer to serialize ALL the fields, then have each *animal* child specify an array of *serializable fields* and then serialize those.
This solution allows you to have one serializer for all subclasses of *animal*.